# how to truncate multiple lines in textarea?

Tags: javascript, substring, textarea

I am trying to create a 2 text area tool where i input upto 300 lines of text into 1 text area it deletes all but the first 5 characters and spits out only those 5 characters in the second text area

please forgive my failed attempts i know my code is all over the place i have tried multiple ways to do this i believed a forloop would be the best but i couldn't get .substring to work

```
function lineParse() {
var parseBoxList = document.getElementById("parsebox").value;
var nodeLength = 5;
var trimFat = parseBoxList.substring(0, nodeLength);
var text = document.getElementById("parsebox").value;   
var lines = text.split('/n');
var cut = lines.substring(0, 5);
var count = lines.length;      
var x = document.getElementById("parsebox").value;

var text2 = "";
  var i;
var parseLength = 5;

  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var text3 = text2;
text2 += lines[i];
}



  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cut;
```

nothing happens

Comment: You are not using the right separator. The newline character is \n not /n.

Comment: have you tried using `text-overflow: ellipsis` style ?

Comment: Also substring must be used on a string, as the name says, so using it on an array won't work.

Comment: Am i missing something or is this what you are trying to achieve?  https://jsfiddle.net/eojxmpga/3/

Comment: @JakoBasson close to what i want to do, but i want it to create an array and slice the array and split each line so lets say i have 1 text area with 10 lines of text that are 40 characters long i need the first 5 characters of all 40 lines to spit out in the second text area

Comment: @crapcoder gotcha, something more like this then? https://jsfiddle.net/zdu6kcvx/3/

Comment: @JakoBasson yes thats actually perfect

Comment: @crapcoder okay great, pasted the code in an answer instead of just the fiddle in the comments. Glad its working

Comment: @JakoBasson I know this is alot but I got it doing what I want now, I am stuck trying to figure out how to make it repeat the same line 99 times and add numbers 1-99 before each line, May sound excessive but its about the numbers before the data so what i have tried so far is to try and add a forloop within the forloop and count 1-99 but it just breaks things so what im trying to do is say its hello world on 2 lines i want to have hello world repeated 198 times 1-99 each time, so 1helloworld 2hello world 3 hello world well just hello. in this case as its only 5 characters

Comment: @JakoBasson I figured it out, Thanks for your help and i managed to alter what you sent to meet the needs I had i appreciate it i was wracking my head on that

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you are looking for with the following code:

HTML

```
<textarea id="textarea1">
this1 is a line 
this2 is a line 
this3 is a line 
this4 is a line 
this5 is a line 
</textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>

<button id="execute">Execute</button>
```

JS

```
function test() {
  // split text area value by newline
  var lines = document.getElementById("textarea1").value.split("\n");

  var newText = "";

  // loop over text area line array and substring each to get the first 5 characters
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    newText += line.substring(0, 5) + "\n";
  }

  // set values to newText variable
  document.getElementById("textarea2").value = newText;
  document.getElementById("textarea1").value = newText;
}

document.getElementById("execute").addEventListener('click', test);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zdu6kcvx/3/